# What is the meaning of nums[complement] in the following line of code return [nums_dict[complement],i] in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

So, I am solving a problem of Two sum which has a following problem statement : **Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

You can return the answer in any order.**

For example :- for the input nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9 , the output should be nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1]. So, I understood the workflow except I am stuck with understanding this this code [nums_dict[complement],i] I understand we return index but simply not able to visualise this LOC. Following is my code

```
class Solution(object):

    def twoSum(self,nums,target):

        nums_dict = {}

        for i,num in enumerate(nums):
            complement = target-num
            if complement in nums_dict:
                return [nums_dict[complement],i]  # are we getting index or value of the dictionary
            else:
                nums_dict[num]=i

        return []

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arr = [2,7,11,15],
    target =9
    print(Solution().twoSum(arr,target))
```

Comment: Do you know what it means *outside* of that line of code?

Comment: Does it mean outside the scope of it ?